# Can I install linux headers package as non-root?

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, linux-kernel-headers

Ubuntu 20.04 - is it possible to install the Linux headers package as non-root? Perhaps to a different directory under $HOME somewhere?

The reason for asking is I would like to have an Jenkins job that periodically fetches and, if necessary, installs the latest version before building a driver against those headers. The Jenkins job will run as a non-root user, so I don't really want to mess with passwords or keys if I can do the whole thing with 'normal' user permissions.

(I have thought about using DKMS, but the machines where the driver will be installed are very restricted and we can't install build tools on them.)

Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because regarding ubuntu should go to https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Having said that, did you do any previous research? https://askubuntu.com/questions/193695/installing-packages-into-local-directory